Error Launching VMs with Virtualbox
Virtualbox worked fine with my VMs for months. Now none of them will launch. Attempts to reinstall virtualbox without deleting the VMs have failed. I'm attaching log 1 from kali linux vm after boot aborted. And I'm including a screenshot. Log1 printout here.


you're running a VM in Kali Linux... That is not part of what Kali is intended for.

@Hannu No, OP is running Kali inside VM, which is recommended

Right, my mistake! An attempt to push this further: A purge of virtualbox (assuming sudo apt purge virtualbox) will not delete the VMs, but will purge any and all settings files. It is easy to add the VMs back into a new install of VBox. The re-installation may be something to try, and also verify to have the latest addons installed.
